# Yosemite Server / Domain Configuration advice

Tags: macos, network, osx-server, server.app, dns

I'm configuring a mac mini server (latest Yosemite) and I'd like some advice/guidance.

I have a registered domain in use for my website, mail and some subdomains – all externally hosted.

I'd like to add a subdomain that points at my mac mini server for public access to jenkins, profile configuration, vpn, etc.

I'd also like the mac mini to handle DHCP, OpenDirectory, and local DNS for the local network.

I've been fighting this for a few days, where pointing the subdomain at my server and then giving the server the appropriate hostname `subdomain.domain.com` causes all kinds of DNS issues, presumably because I've now started, inadvertently, implementing a split-brain DNS configuration. I'd really like to avoid the maintenance of split-brain DNS going forward.

I'm currently running a thunderbolt adapter for ethernet so that the mac mini sits between the modem and the internal switches. With this, I'm able to use Internet sharing to get DHCP working on the network, but the DHCP server service doesn't seem to be active.

Can anyone give me some guidance? I've followed all of the Apple documentation, but I don't see any sections that address either of the 2 main issues I'm running into. They seem to assume that if you're running DNS on the server that it's the DNS for the entire zone (fair assumption on their part).